# Parsing HTML with PowerShell on dynamic sites

Tags: powershell, html-parsing

Is there a way to parse HTML from http://www.pgatour.com site using Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet? When I try doing this, ParsedHtml does not contain elements that I need (because cmdlet incorrectly parses the page).
I tried getting data from this page by creating IE COM object in PowerShell and it works, but very slow, so I'm wondering if there is another approach using Invoke-WebRequest (or even external parsers).

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a .NET parsing library that supports this and calling into that from within powershell?

Comment: I consider using external tools to parse HTML. Do you know any?

Answer (score 0):

You could give the [HmtlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) a try to parse the content returned by `Invoke-WebRequest`.  In this scenario, I would use the `-UseBasicParsing` parameter.

Comment: Yes, I know about this pack, but it does not support CSS locators, and I need this support. I also took a look at Fizzler, but it does not get updated often and is now obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Window 10 64-bit. PowerShell 5.1

Parsing HTML with PowerShell 5.1 on dynamic sites using Invoke-WebRequest and a regex that returns everything between un-nested tags like `<html>,<title>,<head>`, and `<body>`.  It will take some tweaking for nested tags.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://www.pgatour.com | sc golf.html
(gc -raw golf.html) -match '(<body>)(.*|\n).*?(<\/body>)'
$matches[0]
```

Everything between `<div class="success-message">` and the next `</div>`

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://www.pgatour.com | sc golf.html
(gc -raw golf.html) -match '(<div class="success-message">)(.*?|\n)*(<\/div>)'
$matches[0]
```

[Greedy and lazy quantifiers explained](https://javascript.info/regexp-greedy-and-lazy)

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) is your friend.