# Webscraping a table from a website with Powershell

Tags: powershell, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a table that contains bank prime rates.

I currently have the following code that I have taken from the website http://vcloud-lab.com/entries/powershell/powershell-web-scrapping-extract-table-from-html. This works just fine with the table that is from the website https://datatables.net/. I however would need to select a specific table from multiple tables. Then I noticed that the datatables.net gives away the data when I use invoke-webrequest and then use .AllElements on that website and my target website doesn't.

```
#Code section
#Open website
$webSite = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.kauppalehti.fi/porssi/korot/viitekorot

#Find table in the website
$tableHeader = $webSite.AllElements | Where-Object {$_.tagname -eq 'th'}
$tableData = $webSite.AllElements | Where-Object {$_.tagname -eq 'td'}
$tabledata
```

My goal is to have the table of prime rates as an object in PowerShell which I can then reformat into an CSV file.

Comment: The problem with this website is that the tables are dynamically build and not part of the webpage itself.

Comment: @iRon do you know is it possible to do scraping with another way or does this prevent me from scraping the data table completely?

Comment: @HenkkAAAA, I believe [Keith Hill's recomendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37178093/4190564) of using the [HTML Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) is probably your best bet.  I also think YMM's comment/complaint to Keith's answer is invalid as it is getting [updated](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/#versions-body-tab) multiple times per year for several years now.  I've used it, not for dynamic content, and there was for me a little bit of a learning curve.